# Universal app not working on iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, universal

I have build an universal application which works perfectly in iPhone Simulator. But the application crashes in iPad simulator. The execution does not enter in to the AppDelegate of the iPad itself. 
It doesn't throw any errors or anything just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ... somehow in .xib the delegate wasn't connected to File's Owner. Silly mistake. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Also, I've seen people get this wrong by not having the "Target Device Family" build setting set correctly.